# iOS CocoaHttpServer works on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, cocoahttpserver

I want to use CocoaHtttpServer to build a server on my iPhone. and I have the code like this

```

```
 _httpServer = [[HTTPServer alloc] init];
[_httpServer setPort:50517];
[_httpServer setType:@"_http._tcp."];

NSString *webResourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"web"];
[_httpServer setDocumentRoot:webResourcePath];
[_httpServer setConnectionClass:[MyHTTPConnection class]];
NSError *err;
if([_httpServer start:&err]){
     NSLog(@"start server success in port %d %@",[_httpServer listeningPort],[_httpServer publishedName]);
}else{
    NSLog(@"%@",err);
}
NSString *ipStr = [LGUtils getIpAddresses1];
NSLog(@"ip address : %@",ipStr);
```

```

It works on simulator, the logged address is `10.134.0.97`, also it's my

mac's IP, I could access the server in the simulator by

`10.134.0.97:50517`. Until now everything was working normally.

But when I installed the app in my iPad (iOS 12.0), and I run the app, it

also log the ip address  `10.134.0.107`, but when I use this address

`10.134.0.107:50517` to access my server, the browser tells me that I can't access the server, I have try the `ping` in console, every thing is ok, so what's the wrong place?

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/656600

Comment: @rptwsthi Thanks for that, I have configured the `Allow Arbitrary Loads`  to YES,  It works on simulator but not device, if the configuration has something wrong, it couldn't works on simulator, right?